# Jquery line animation with Lazy Line Painter

Tags: jquery, animation

i have been experimenting with some jquery animation from vector(svg) files, my approach was good but terribly slow to write the code for simple lines until i found this excellent little help at

http://lazylinepainter.info/

Extremely helpful its just the thing i was searching for. Using this i made this line animation:

http://bit.ly/YSL5qd

As you can see the animation works with multiple paths, the only thing i cant figure out is how to lunch the two lines at the same time.
I tried to implement the paths in two different js files, it wont work...

Any ideas?
Thanks in forwards!

The markup:

```
 <div id="svg7" style="width: 1022px; height: 150px; z-index: 9999; position: absolute; top: 50px;"></div>


        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="scripts/strokengine.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/pulsengine.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your path data into two separates key/values pairs,

assign the animation to a second div,

then setup your properties & "paint" (svg8) separately.

```
var pathObj = {
    "svg7": {
        "strokepath": [
            {
                "path": " ... "
            }
        ],
        "dimensions": { ... }
    },
    /* second key / value */ 
    "svg8": {           
        "strokepath": [ 
            {
               "path": "..."
            }
        ],
        "dimensions": { ... }
    }
}; 

<div id="svg7"></div>
<div id="svg8"></div>  


// second lazyline instance
$('#svg8').lazylinepainter({
     "svgData": pathObj,
     "strokeWidth": 3,
     "strokeColor": "#89171a"
}).lazylinepainter('paint');
```

see below;

http://jsfiddle.net/J8nC3/4/

This is an area of lazylinepainter that will be simpler to implement in the near future.

thank cam